# R Converting POSIXlt to xts

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, xts

I have a time series in the format:

```
> str(Y$Date)
POSIXlt[1:174110], format: "2001-01-01 12:00:00" "2001-01-01 05:30:00" "2001-01-02 01:30:00" "2001-01-02 02:00:00" "2001-01-02 02:00:00" "2001-01-02 02:01:00" "2001-01-02 04:00:00" "2001-01-02 04:00:00" ...

> summary(Y$Date)
                 Min.               1st Qu.                Median                  Mean               3rd Qu.                  Max. 
"2001-01-01 05:30:00" "2004-03-15 10:40:30" "2007-01-03 04:00:00" "2006-11-11 15:53:11" "2009-08-13 12:00:00" "2011-12-30 12:30:00" 

> length(Y$Date)
[1] 174110
```

which I need to convert to a xts format. In order to do so I have done the following:

```
date <- Y$Date
date <- as.xts(date)
> xtsible(date) #tests wheather or not the data is convertibal to format xts
[1] TRUE
```

However:

```
> str(date)
An 'xts' object of zero-width
> length(date)
[1] 0

> head(date['2001'])
                    [,1]
2001-01-01 05:30:00   NA
2001-01-01 12:00:00   NA
2001-01-02 01:30:00   NA
2001-01-02 02:00:00   NA
2001-01-02 02:00:00   NA
2001-01-02 02:00:00   NA
```

and in order to get the data back into the data frame:

```
> Y$date <- date
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "date", value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 174110
```

and

```
> as.data.frame(date)
Error in data.frame(`coredata(x)` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_,  : 
   duplicate row.names: 2001-01-02 02:00:00, ... , 2001-01-08 06:00:00, 200
In addition: Warning message:
In format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE) :
  corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs

> str(Y)
'data.frame':   174110 obs. of  17 variables:
 $ Date    : POSIXlt, format: "2001-01-01 12:00:00" "2001-01-01 05:30:00" "2001-01-02 01:30:00" "2001-01-02 02:00:00" ...
 $ C       : chr  "MA" "IN" "SI" "ID" ...
 $ Event   : chr  "MALAY VEHICLE SALES" "Interbank Offer Rate - Percent" "Advance GDP Estimate (YoY)" "Foreign Reserves" ...
 $ News    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Growth  : num  148 NA 0.3 387.2 0 ...
 $ Surv.M  : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Act     : num  30892 NA 10.5 29281.4 12500 ...
 $ Prior   : num  30744 8100 10.2 28894.2 12500 ...
 $ Revised : num  NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Type    : chr  NA NA "%" "$B" ...
 $ Freq.   : chr  "M" "NA" "Q" "M" ...
 $ Ticker  : chr  "MAVSTTL Index" "IMIBOR Index" "SGAVYOY% Index" "IDGFA Index" ...
 $ Period  : chr  "Nov" "12/31/13" "4Q" "Dec" ...
 $ Category: chr  "NA" "NA" "NA" "NA" ...
 $ Time    : chr  "12:00:00 AM" "05:30:00 AM" "01:30:00 AM" "02:00:00 AM" ...
 $ Country : chr  "Malaysia" "India" "Singapore" "Indonesia" ...
 $ date    : POSIXlt, format: "2001-01-01 12:00:00" "2001-01-01 05:30:00" "2001-01-02 01:30:00" "2001-01-02 02:00:00" ...
```

I don"t know why I can't properly convert the data into the xts format and then get them back into the dataframe.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please paste output of `str(Y)` as well.

Comment: What do I not understand here? To me it seems that you are trying to extract dates from a data frame, create an `xts` object with these dates as `Index`, extract the dates from `xts`, and then put them back in the data frame. Unchanged. And: "in order to get **the data** back into the data frame"; your `xts` object doesn't have any data, only an `Index`, i.e. the dates you picked from the data frame. Maybe you could add a sentence or two about your overall objectives. Cheers.

Comment: Sure Henrik. Anything I can do to help. I need to analyze changes of some of these variable over time, for different periods (for. ex from 01-02 and 01-04 etc). I already posted the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188302/simple-time-interval-in-r and followed it's advice, which was to change the POSIXlt format to xts. However, in so doing I encountered to problem described above. And your analysis is right on the spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered a similar question asked by you previously. I guess it has caused some confusion. When you see `?xts`, it says that `xts` creates an "extensible time-series" object.  First we have to specify `x`, the object of which time-series has to be made and then specify the index, i.e. the time-series itself (`Y$Date` in your case).

Here is a simplified solution:

```
Y_new <- xts(x = Y[,-1], order.by = Y$Date]
```

This creates a new object `Y_new` in the time-series format with all the data of `Y` and with an added benefit easily choosing desired time intervals.

Comment: Thank you again Striker! You really saved my day.